# How to Construct SOAP XML Request in apex

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>

  </SOAP-ENV:Header>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help me in building the XML Request Structure in apex.I have started like this Is this Correct?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create XML using String concatenation.  This makes generated XML very much readable.

```
String requestInput = '?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
        '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope '+
        ' xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '+
        ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '+
        ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> '+
        ' <SOAP-ENV:Header> '+
        ' </SOAP-ENV:Header>';
```

Comment: Thanks for that but can i do it in the way i have mentioned above if possible can i get any help.

Comment: You can refer this example, as its pretty standard. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm

Answer (score 0):

I favor using the [DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Dom.htm) classes as you suggest in your question. The code then reflects the nested structure of the data and importantly any escaping that is needed is done automatically.

(This may be overkill if only one or two pieces of data vary.)

Here is part of a class where we do that where the content can vary a lot:

```
public class Xyz {

    private static final String SE_NAMESPACE = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
    private static final String SE_PREFIX = 'se';

    private static final String FT_NAMESPACE = 'http://fasttrackrtw.com/services/';
    private static final String FT_PREFIX = 'te';

    private class RequestBuilder {

        Dom.Document doc;
        Dom.XMLNode create;

        RequestBuilder() {

            // Created SOAP envelope, header and body and create elements
            doc = new Dom.Document();
            Dom.XMLNode envelope = doc.createRootElement('Envelope', SE_NAMESPACE, SE_PREFIX);
            create = envelope
                .addChildElement('Body', SE_NAMESPACE, SE_PREFIX)
                .addChildElement('CreateUpdateTSTClaimant', FT_NAMESPACE, FT_PREFIX);
        }

        Dom.Document getDocument() {
            return doc;
        }

        RequestBuilder add(String name, Object value) {
            createElementAndTextNode(name, value);
            return this;
        }

        RequestBuilder add(String name, SObject sob, SObjectField field) {
            if (sob != null) {
                createElementAndTextNode(name, sob.get(field));
            }
            return this;
        }

        private void createElementAndTextNode(String name, Object value) {
            if (value != null) {
                if (value instanceof String) {
                    create.addChildElement(name, FT_NAMESPACE, FT_PREFIX).addTextNode((String) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                    Date d = (Date) value;
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());
                    create.addChildElement(name, FT_NAMESPACE, FT_PREFIX).addTextNode(dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'));
                } else if (value instanceof Decimal) {
                    Decimal d = (Decimal) value;
                    create.addChildElement(name, FT_NAMESPACE, FT_PREFIX).addTextNode(String.valueOf(d));
                } else {
                    throw new FastTrackErrorException('Unexpected field type for name=' + name + ' value=' + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The main thing is to fill in the second and third arguments for the namespace and prefix.